# Low Search 6.1.0 Throws "No such method getAllCustomFields" Error

Tags: ee3, low-search, php-errors

I've recently installed Low Search 6.1.0 on an EE 3.5.16 install and when I try to create a collection, I get the following error:

> **Exception Caught**
>
> **No such method getAllCustomFields.**
>
> ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mixin/Manager.php:143

Anyone else encounter this?

Answer (score 0):

V6 of Low Search is compatible with EE4, see https://c.getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low-search-6-1-0-throws-no-such-method-getallcustomfields-error